# How to send an array by i2c?

Tags: python, arrays, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I've been trying for several days now to send a python array by i2c.

```
data = [x,x,x,x] # `x` is a number from 0 to 127.
bus.write_i2c_block_data(i2c_address, 0, data)

bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, cmd, array)
```

In the function above: addr - arduino i2c adress; cmd - Not sure what this is; array - python array of int numbers. 
 Can this be done? What is actually the cmd?

---

FWIW, Arduino code, where I receive the array and put it on the `byteArray`:

> ```
> void receiveData(int numByte){
>     int i = 0;
>     while(wire.available()){
>         if(i < 4){
>             byteArray[i] = wire.read();
>             i++;
>         }
>      }
>   }
> ```

---

It gives me this error: 
 `bus.write_i2c_block_data(i2c_adress, 0, decodedArray) IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error.` 
I tried with this: `bus.write_byte(i2c_address, value)`, and it worked, but only for a `value` that goes from 0 to 127, but, I need to pass not only a value, but a full array.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question. Could you review it. In addition, could you explain what is "not working" ? Syntax error ? data not send ? ... ?

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your help. i Tried your solution, and it still gives me the same error: bus.write_i2c_block_data(i2c_adress, 0, decodedArray)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error.

I'am out of ideas...

Comment: I didn't try to provide an answer. Just to fix your question formating. If you have more info, like the error message above, please *edit you question* to mention it. Other peoples will not necessary take the time to "dig" into the comments to find various clues.

Comment: Just did that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while,but i got it working.

On the arduino side:

```
int count = 0;
...

...
void receiveData(int numByte){

    while(Wire.available()){
      if(count < 4){
        byteArray[count] = Wire.read();
        count++;
      }
      else{
        count = 0;
        byteArray[count] = Wire.read();
      }
    }
}
```

On the raspberry side:

```
def writeData(arrayValue):

    for i in arrayValue:
        bus.write_byte(i2c_address, i)
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 3):

The function is the good one.

But you should take care of some points:

- bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, cmd, []) send the value of cmd AND the values in the list on the I2C bus.

So

```
bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x20, 42, [12, 23, 34, 45])
```

doesn't send 4 bytes but 5 bytes to the device.

I doesn't know how the wire library work on arduino, but the device only read 4 bytes, it doesn't send the ACK for the last bytes and the sender detect an output error.

- Two convention exist for I2C device address. The I2C bus have 7 bits for device address and a bit to indicate a read or a write. An other (wrong) convention is to write the address in 8 bits, and say that you have an address for read, and an other for write. The smbus package use the correct convention (7 bits).

Exemple: 0x23 in 7 bits convention, become 0x46 for writing, and 0x47 for reading.

Comment: Ok that explained really well the i2c protocol, but what i can't understand is what cmd value is used for? I tried again and again and it keep failing. Sorry to be a newbie.

Comment: In practice the byte of cmd and bytes of data are all send exactly the same way. The general use case in I2C is to write a value in a register. So you select the device address, the register on the device, and after you write your data.

Comment: I think the problem you have is in the arduino code, or electrical. I suggest you to try with a compliant I2C device first before trying to communicate to your arduino. (eeprom, thermal captor... lot of cheap chip exist)

Comment: I totally agree with you, but the i2c is functional, i can send a byte and receive it, i just can't send an array of data. And that's what i really need.

Comment: I already use this particular function a lot of time without any problem sending plenty of data. The fact it's functional with only one byte but not more made me nearly sure it's a problem on the arduino side. (Witch I never used, can't help)

Comment: How do you define the cmd value? A random value? The array is well defined, the cmd value i made it up, but it won't work, is the cmd value a specific value?

Comment: @Cld additional question-- [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol) on write_block_data say it can send up to 32 bytes of data. So the array in the third argument....is that one byte per int, and a max length of 4 on the array? I thought ints were 2-4 bytes each....what are the rules there?

Answer (score 0):

cmd is offset on which you want to write a data.
so its like

```
bus.write_byte(i2c_address, offset, byte)
```

but if you want to write array of bytes then you need to write block data so your code will look like this

```
bus.write_i2c_block_data(i2c_address, offset, [array_of_bytes])
```